Simulate joint holding in gazebo
I am building a simulation of a custom-designed robotic arm. In the simulation, I am controlling it using 'effort_controllers/JointVelocityController'. However, I want the joint to remain still when the velocity reference is 0, and as of right now, with a reference equal to 0 or close to it, the joint falls instead. I am getting up the joints like this:
<xacro:macro name="rev_junc" params="name parent child xyz rpy axis effort vel" >
    <joint name="${name}" type="continuous">
        <parent link="${parent}"/>
        <child link="${child}"/>
        <origin rpy="${rpy}" xyz="${xyz}"/>
        <limit effort="${effort}" velocity="${vel}"/>
        <axis xyz="${axis}"/>
    </joint>
</xacro:macro>

Is there any way I can achieve the explained behavior?

Have you tried increasing the allowable joint effort, and decreasing the simulation max_step_size?

Yes, but the issue still persists. The joints I'm using have holding torque, but I haven't been able to successfully represent that in the simulation
